# acceder a una pagina desde dos links distintos

Tags: php, mysqli, enlace

estoy retomando php despues de un largo tiempo y tengo el siguiente inconveniente, necesito acceder a una pagina web desde dos links distintos y cada link lleva una variable diferente y no tengo la menor idea de como realizarlo, ya que si accedo desde algunos de los links la pagina siempre me tira que esta indefinida la otra variable, en el archivo principal tengo esto:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse texto" id="menu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto text-light">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Categoria
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu sub_bg-navbar" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <?php
             if ($inc){
              $consulta = "SELECT DISTINCT `categoria_producto` FROM `productos`";
              $resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta);
              if ($resultado){
                  while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()){
                      $categoria = $row['categoria_producto']; ?>
                      <li><a href="seccion.php?categoria=<?php echo $categoria; ?>" class='dropdown-item'><?php echo $categoria; ?> </a><li><?php
                  }
              }
          }
          ?>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

este seria un menu donde accedo a la pagina secciones con la variable categoria

```
<section class="row justify-content-evenly">
<?php
    if ($inc){
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM `productos`";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta);
    if ($resultado){
        while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()){
        $id = $row['id_producto'];
        $categoria = $row['categoria_producto'];
        $nombre = $row['nombre_producto'];
        $img = $row['img_producto'];
        $descripcion = $row['descripcion_producto'];
        $precio = $row['precio_producto'];?>
        <article class='col-md-4 col-12 my-3'>
            <div class='card'>
                <a href="seccion.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="img/<?php echo $img; ?>" class='card-img-top' alt='...'></a>
                <div class='card-body px-4'>
                    <h5 class='card-title'><?php echo ucwords($nombre); ?> </h5>
                    <p class='card-text'><?php echo $descripcion; ?></p>
                    <a class='btn btn-success'>$ <?php echo $precio; ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
                <?php  }
              }
          }
          ?>
</section>
```

esta parte del codigo se encuentra en el mismo archivo principal y desde aca accedo a la pagina seccion.php mediante la variable id

*seccion.php*

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
$categoria = $_GET['categoria'];
?>
<section class="row justify-content-evenly">
<?php
         if ($inc){
          $consulta = "SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `id_producto` LIKE '$categoria' ORDER BY `categoria_producto` ASC";
          $resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta);
          if ($resultado){
              while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()){
                  $categoria = $row['categoria_producto'];
                  $nombre = $row['nombre_producto'];
                  $img = $row['img_producto'];
                  $descripcion = $row['descripcion_producto'];
                  $precio = $row['precio_producto'];?>
                  <article class='col-md-4 col-12 my-3'>
    <div class='card'>
        <a href="seccion.php?categoria=<?php echo $categoria; ?>"><img src="img/<?php echo $img; ?>" class='card-img-top' alt='...'></a>
        <div class='card-body px-4'>
            <h5 class='card-title'><?php echo ucwords($nombre); ?> </h5>
            <p class='card-text'><?php echo $descripcion; ?></p>
            <a class='btn btn-success'>$ <?php echo $precio; ?></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
            <?php  }
          }
      }
      ?>
</section>
```

este es el codigo que tengo en el archivo seccion.php, asi como esta siempre me tira indefinido una u otra variable, se le ocurre alguna idea a los que mas saben?

---

gracias por tu respuesta, ese codigo me sirvio pero me esta pasando algo raro en el else, en el if todo bien me tira el resultado buscado pero en el else no:

```
else{
        if ($inc){
        $categoria = $_GET['categoria'];
        var_dump($categoria);
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `categoria_producto` = $categoria";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta);
        var_dump($resultado);
            if ($resultado){
                while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()){
                $id = $row['id_producto'];
                $categoria = $row['categoria_producto'];
                $nombre = $row['nombre_producto'];
                $img = $row['img_producto'];
                $descripcion = $row['descripcion_producto'];
                $precio = $row['precio_producto'];?>
                <article class='col-md-4 col-12 my-3'>
                    <div class='card'>
                        <a href="seccion.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="img/<?php echo $img; ?>" class='card-img-top' alt='...'></a>
                        <div class='card-body px-4'>
                            <h5 class='card-title'><?php echo ucwords($nombre); ?> </h5>
                            <p class='card-text'><?php echo $descripcion; ?></p>
                            <a class='btn btn-success'>$ <?php echo $precio; ?></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                        <?php  }
                      }
                  }
    }
```

el primer var_dump me muestra que la variable se trae, pero el segundo no me tira nada, me tira lo siguiente: bool(false)

@braian romero

Answer (score 0):

lo que entiendo que es tu problema, es que si envias una variable te dice que la otra no esta definida.
para solucionar eso se me ocurre que deberias preguntar si existe la variable primero y en base a eso hacer la consulta.

```
if(isset($_GET['id'] && isset($_GET['categoria'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $categoria = $_GET['categoria'];
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `id_producto` = '.$id.' AND `id_categoria` = '.$categoria.' ORDER BY `categoria_producto` ASC";
}
else if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `id_producto` = '.$id.' ORDER BY `categoria_producto` ASC";
}
else if(isset($_GET['categoria'])){
    $categoria = $_GET['categoria'];
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `id_categoria` = '.$categoria.' ORDER BY `categoria_producto` ASC";
```

- no te olvides de concatenar la variable en la consulta, que tambien te puede dar problemas
- en el caso de los id debes usar el operador igual '=' en vez de LIKE
  @braian romero

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, ese codigo me sirvio pero a media, me pasa algo raro con el else, el primer if todo bien me da el resultado buscado pero el else no

Comment: Va bien encaminada la respuesta, solo falta considerar que no se haya proporcionado tampoco la variable `categoria` y se soluciona cambiando `else` por `elseif(isset($_GET['categoria']))`

Comment: ahi lo corregí para que funcione en todas las situaciones posibles